# Jquery Mobile Application Strange Behaviour

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, cordova

I have created one application which contains several buttons to home page clicking on one of that button my application redirects to some view which contains JQM form, with JQM calendar, text field, buttons and database etc....

My query is that when I test my application in android device on that time application works a little bit slow, even if I have not used any images,or any data which can contain more space. That's my first query and second one is that when I tested my application to android tablet on that time that form page is appearing for a while and suddenly it redirects back to home page automatically, while this same feature working well for android phone.

Why this strange issue?

If any one can guide me on it that it will be my pleasure

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile? What version of PhoneGap? What have you done so far to attempt a fix? Can you show some code, for instance, the order of JS includes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difficult to make assumptions regarding the slow performance and the redirection issue. Below you can find some aspects which in my opinion affect the performance of a mobile application which consists of HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and should be taken into consideration on the analysis, the design and the development phase.

**Implementation method based on the size**

When developing small mobile applications the usage of a single HTML page using internal-AJAX page linking is recommended. For bigger mobile applications, a method of using different HTML pages with internal-AJAX linking is recommended. Try to create reusable page templates.

**Page Transitions**

As stated in the [jQM 1.1.1 Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html), by default, all transitions except fade require 3D transform support. Devices that lack 3D support will fall back to a fade transition, regardless of the transition specified. jQM does this this to proactively exclude poorly-performing platforms like Android 2.x from advanced transitions and ensure they still have a smooth experience. Note that there are platforms such as Android 3.0 that technically support 3D transforms, but still have poor animation performance so this won't guarantee that every browser will be 100% flicker-free. Decide the transition type that you will use after considering the above.

**Minify JS and CSS files**

Each page should be as lightweight as possible. The minification’s goal is to preserve the operational qualities of the code while reducing its overall byte footprint. There are a lot of tools available on the WEB like the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), the [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) and many more. Furthermore there are tools like the [JLint](http://www.jslint.com/) which is used to check whether JavaScript source code complies with coding rules. [JLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a code quality tool which checks for problems in the JavaScript code. The reported problems are not necessarily syntax errors but may be structural problems. Note that JLint does not prove that your code is correct. Consider it as a helping tool. Also there are tools for performing CSS optimization. The optimization helps you to get smaller CSS file sizes and better written code.  You can find a lot of CSS optimizers available on the WEB such as [CleanCSS](http://www.cleancss.com/index.php) and [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/).

**Components limits**

The HTML pages is recommended to be limited to 25kb in order to gain the optimal caching advantage for the majority of the mobile web browsers. The caching limit varies depending on the OS version. For example Android 2.1 has a caching limit of approximately 2Mb.

**HTML5 & CSS3**

Try to create easy to read, to extend and reusable code. It is important to take full advantage of the using of HTML5 and CSS3. The HTML5 DocType declaration (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) should be the first thing in your HTML5 document before the html tag. It is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

**Use the [W3C mobileOK Checker](http://validator.w3.org/mobile/)**

The [W3C mobileOK Checker](http://validator.w3.org/mobile/) is a free service by W3C that helps check the level of mobile friendliness of Web documents, and in particular assert whether a Web document is mobileOK. A Web Page is mobileOK when it passes all the tests. The tests are defined in the mobileOK [Basic Tests 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/). To understand why checking a Web document for mobile-friendliness really matters, it is probably worth emphasizing a few points about the so-called mobile world. Compared to a regular desktop computer, a mobile device may be regarded as limited at first glance: smaller screen size, smaller processing powers, smaller amount of memory, no mouse, and so on. Compared to fixed data connections, mobile networks can be slow and often have a higher latency. Compared to a user sitting in front of his computer, the user on the go has limited time and is easily distracted. On top of these constraints, the mobile world is highly fragmented: many different devices, each of them defining a unique set of supported features.

**Consider the appearance on different screen sizes**

The screens density and the viewport size and web page’s scale should be taken into consideration when targeting different screen sizes. The viewport metadata can be used to define the viewport size where viewport is the container area in which the page is drawn. The viewport scale defines the zoom level which is applied to the web page. The target-densitydpi viewport property and CSS, JS techniques can be used to change the target screen density for the web page. There are plenty of articles on the WEB regarding the appearance on different screen sizes.

**Identify the flows with potential delay**

The [PageSpeed Firefox/Chrome extension](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) can be used to check the pages speed. When you profile a web page with Page Speed, it evaluates the page's conformance to a number of different rules. These rules are general front-end best practices you can apply at any stage of web development. The extension gives specific tips and suggestions on how to best implement the rules and incorporate them into the development process.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks This Your Answer is Really Helpful to me,it's really nice to take this all thing in consideration while we are developing cross platform application.i will recomend this to other phonegap developer as well so that they also can get banifit out of it.thanks again for nice response.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) The above answer is personal opinion and wat my experience has showed. Maybe someone else considers different performance aspects. Thanks

Comment: I believe that it covers and documents the important performance aspects of mobile applications which are developed using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. Thank you and I hope that my answer helps.

Comment: well thanks again,it will be my pleasure if u can come http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-phones-developer in this room and have some conversation with me whenever u have time thanks

Comment: Yes of course, I will join the chat as soon as I will find free time. Thanks